# Is it a getter in scala? (from the RDD class source of Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When we do checkpointing in spark, we go through a statement that:

```
checkpointData.get.doCheckPoint()
```

Why not instead use `checkpointData.doCheckPoint()`?
Is the `get` in the statement something like getter? I know that scala class will automatically generate getter and setter.

Or is it some other syntax I do not know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about source code of RDD class (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala), then it's because `checkpointData` has type of `Option[RDDCheckpointData[T]]`

See declaration in source code:

```
private[spark] var checkpointData: Option[RDDCheckpointData[T]] = ...
```

So to do call a method of RDDCheckpointData we need to get it from Option (after being sure it `isDefined`, as you can see in code)

Read more about scala Option class:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html